# Very simple phone functionality - what do I really need?

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, voip

I would like to try to implement very simple VoIP phone functionality in my Xamarin application (both Android and iOS). By very simple I mean no dictionary of users, no "hold", no addresses (like on SIP).

A basical scenario is: The app has button to "call support". The app knows IP of the other side, so just try an UDP connection to the known IP, and if someone there press "Accept" button, there can speak to each other until someone hits "hang up" button.

Now, I am totally new in whole VoIP, so basically my question is, what should I be looking for? Do I need "SIP stack" and "RTP stack" (whatever that is, I justed googled a little before asking this question :)

Or can I do it in a much more simpler way? For example I found this Xamarin forum page:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2526/udpclient-in-background - someone using IAX2, which I assume is this: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/IAXClient, but the link on C# wrapper seems invalid now :/

Comment: To answer your question above on RTP: SIP is the protocol that sets up the 'call' - i.e. it says I am John and I want to speak to Mary. RTP is the protocol that actually carries the speech between the two parties when the call has been set up - i.e. the packets containing the encoded speech.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to 'go with the flow' here and simply use SIP - VoIP is theoretically relatively simple, but has plenty of complexity in the details. And, while it is true to say that SIP has grown into a large complex beast, using a standard approach that many others are using means you not only get the benefit of someone else having done the low level work for you, but you also leverage a large developer and user community.

You also may find that your simply use case suffers from the usual feature creep or enhancement requests over time (for example different help desks for different support teams or when the user moves to different regions). It will likely be easier to handle these new requirements if your implementation is built on one of the standard SIP approaches.

For Android you may also be able to use the built in SIP API if it is supported in your market/carried and if you don't need to support older versions of Android. Either way there are quite a few well documented SIP libraries for Andorid and iOS these days.